# Laravel cashier in rest api

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a rest api for a new web system. The api is made using the laravel framework, and I've also created a client application which is a separate laravel site. The client just uses guzzle to connect to the api, I've done it like this because we will eventually have an app connecting to the main api.

The issue is that the [php sdk for braintree payments](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php_example) doesn't directly support laravel very well, and the [laravel cashier](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/billing#invoices) site seems to be for taking payment on the same website. 

I'd like to know if anyone has done this before? How would you setup the separate laravel site so that it can take payments in some way via the rest api?

Comment: What problem have you run into ? Have you tried something yet ?

Comment: I've installed laravel cashier but in the docs it doesn't have any information about the payment details being sent. I believe you're supposed to use the braintree js drop in but that obviously can't work with the api.@Pogrindis

Comment: You linked to the example, but the actual Braintree PHP sdk is at https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php

Comment: @aynber Cheers they didn't give that link in the docs however that is for a single php application I'm looking to use this in laravel.

Comment: You can still use it in Laravel. You may need to copy the files into a directory and reference that. I've done that with an "unsupported" library in Laravel 4.2 by adding it into app/lib. I think the process would be only slightly different for newer versions of Laravel.

Comment: okay thanks for your help I'll give it a go @aynber